# AVX-512 - How to gather data from memory using assembly instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, nasm, simd, avx512

I'm trying to gather 64-bit integers from memory using the assembler instruction. Below you can see how I call `assembly` code from `C`. Please notice that assembly code uses `NASM` syntax.

`nasm_gather.asm` file

```
bits 64

        section .text
global nasm_gather:function

extern base_addr
extern vindex

nasm_gather:
        ; prolog
        push            rbp
        push            rbx
        push            r12
        push            r13

        mov             r12         ,[rel base_addr]                ; r12 point to base_addr
        mov             r13         ,[rel vindex]                   ; r13 points to vindex
        vmovdqu32       zmm1        ,[r13]                          ; zmm1 = [2, 5, 1, 3, 0, 4, 7, 6]
        vpxorq          zmm2        ,zmm2               ,zmm2       ; zmm2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        vpgatherqq      zmm2        ,[r12 + zmm1*8]                 ; ----> Illegal instruction at address = ...
        ...
        ; epilog
        pop             r13
        pop             r12
        pop             rbx
        pop             rbp
        ret
```

`main.cpp` file

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" int nasm_gather();

const int N=32;
int64_t* base_addr /*__attribute__ ((aligned (64)))*/  = (int64_t *) malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * N);
int64_t* vindex =  (int64_t *) malloc(sizeof(int64_t) * 8);


int main() {
    /* initialize indices */
    vindex[0]=2; vindex[1]=5; vindex[2]=1; vindex[3]=3;
    vindex[4]=0; vindex[5]=4; vindex[6]=7; vindex[7]=6;
    // ...
    int64_t result = nasm_gather();
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

(`vpgatherqq zmm, vm64z` assembler instruction corresponds to the [_mm512_i64gather_epi64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=3084,6171,133,113,100,118,109,417,2972,3084&text=_mm512_i64gather_epi64&techs=AVX_512) intrinsic function in C)

Just as the programm reaches this point:

```
vpgatherqq      zmm2        ,[r12 + zmm1*8]
```

I get the Illegal instruction error:

> Illegal instruction at address = 4011f0: 62 d2 fd 48 91 14 cc 62 f1 7e
> 48 6f c2 e8 10
> If you believe your application should attempt to
> execute this illegal instruction (and others that may be present),
> Then use this knob: -emit-illegal-insts 0 and this error message will
> be avoided.

What's the problem?

Comment: `mov r12, [rel base_addr]` will load `r12` with the value from `base_addr[0]`, whereas I think you just want it to contain the address of `base_addr`.  So I think you want `lea r12, [rel base_addr]` instead.  Likewise for the following line.  Though I'd still expect a segmentation fault instead of an illegal instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge I get the same error message `Illegal instruction at address = 4011dc: 62 d2 fd 48 91 14 cc 62 f1 7e 48 6f c2 e8 07`

Comment: A mask is required.  NASM uses the same syntax as Intel: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpgatherqd:vpgatherqq.  Or compile C with the intrinsic, and look at the asm.  (`gcc -O2 -march=skylake-avx512 -masm=intel`).  Also, https://uops.info/ will have example assembly syntax of exactly what they microbenchmarked.

Comment: But seriously, if you just want to use `vpgatherqq` from C, use `_mm512_mask_i64gather_epi64` from `immintrin.h`.  https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,AVX_512,Other&expand=5322,3421,3085&text=vpgatherqq.  And don't use global variables to pass args!  I hope you're not actually planning to use that for performance.

Comment: Oh wait a minute, illegal instruction?  Are you running this inside an emulator like SDE?  That *could* be due to a missing mask register.  I'm surprised NASM assembled this without a mask register, but that could be why it creates illegal machine code.  (i.e. the encoding that would mean k0 means unmasked, and that's illegal for gathers; they need somewhere to record partial progress if interrupted e.g. by #PF.)

Comment: @PeterCordes You are right. I am running this inside an emulator.
tried the following:   
`kxnorw  k1 ,k0 ,k0` // k1 = 255
`vpgatherqq  zmm2{k1} ,[r12 + zmm1*8] `
But I get same error message.

Comment: Did you tell your emulator to enable AVX-512?  Which emulator is it?  Also note that your comment is wrong; kxnorW will produce 65535.  Or as most people would write, -1 or 0xFFFF

Comment: Compiler flag looks like this:  `-fno-pie -no-pie  -mavx512f`

Comment: GCC isn't an emulator, it doesn't *run* your code, so its flags have zero effect on whether your emulator will allow AVX-512 machine-code to execute.  You don't even need `-mavx512f` for this code, or immintrin.h, because you're not using `__m512i`.  GCC's C->asm step doesn't see any SIMD stuff, just a function call.  (So it's terrible for efficiency.)

Comment: Now I am using XNOR of 8-bit masks `kxnorb k, k, k` , but problem remains the same

Comment: @PeterCordes reply for "GCC's C->asm step doesn't see any SIMD stuff, ...": If so, why could I execute another SIMD instructions (like  `vmovdqu32`, `kxnorb`) successfully?

Comment: @him You did not answer Peter's question on what emulator you are using (or what parameters you are passing to it). In your case that would be part of an [mre] (as well as code which actually compiles, i.e., get rid of the `...`)

Comment: @chtz I am using [Intel SDE](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-software-development-emulator.html) and pass the following parameter to it: `sde64 -icl    -- ./main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Gathers need a mask** (so they can record progress if interrupted, or if one element faults).  NASM normally doesn't let you assemble illegal instructions without a warning; it's a NASM bug that it doesn't help you spot this error.

Also, your entire approach of using globals instead of function args is bad for both maintainability and performance.  **Use intrinsics** like a normal person if you're already willing to tell GCC it can emit AVX-512 instructions (`-march=skylake-avx512`) and to `#include <immintrin.h>` in your source.  e.g. **`_mm512_mask_i64gather_epi64`**.  Calling any function at all instead of inlining the gather instruction is going to cost a significant fraction of the cost of a gather, and more than that if it's a clunky inefficient function written that way.  Gathers are pretty questionable if your indices aren't already in a SIMD vector, and it certainly doesn't help to use a pointer stored in a global var for the index, instead of passing a pointer arg for the gather function to load a vector of indices from somewhere.

---

**The following code runs fine for me**, in SDE 8.33.0, NASM 2.15.05.  You claim that adding `{k1}` doesn't fix the problem for you.  Either your version of SDE is broken, or you're doing something else wrong.  Or you forgot to rebuild your executable from the updated source.

```
default rel
global _start
_start:
    lea     rax, [rel buf]      ; dummy base = static array.  In a function, use RDI (first int/pointer arg)
    vpxor   xmm1, xmm1,xmm1     ; ZMM1 = dummy index = all zeros, efficiently done with a VEX-coded AVX instruction

    kxnorb      k1, k0,k0           ; mask = -1
    vpxor       xmm0, xmm0,xmm0     ; optional: dependency-breaking before merge-masking.  GCC will do this for the intrinsic.
    vpgatherqq  zmm0{k1}, [rax + zmm1*8]
        
    mov eax, 231
    syscall             ; exit_group(RDI)

section .bss
buf: resd 1024
```

I *can* reproduce that SDE error message if I remove the `{k1}`, making it unmasked like your original question.  NASM 2.15.05 errors if you try to use `{k1}{z}` - Gathers only support merge-masking (again so it can resume after a partial execution interrupted by a #PF or possibly interrupt).  But with correct source, it builds and runs just fine in a static executable.  The host CPU is an i7-6700k Skylake-client (which doesn't support AVX-512, so it's up to SDE to make it work).

```
$ nasm -felf64 avx512-gather.asm
$ ld -o avx512-gather avx512-gather.o
$ /opt/sde-external-8.33.0-2019-02-07-lin/sde64 -- ./avx512-gather
$ echo $?
0
```

(`sde64 -icl` works, too, of course.)

Linking the same machine code into a function callable from C++ would run the same way, but again, that would be pointless when you can use intrinsics (and disassemble with `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out` to see how GCC used the instruction.)

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this out.

Comment: Why do you zero `zmm0`? Do the individual loads to `zmm0` have a dependency on the rest of the register or something?

Comment: @Noah: gathers are only available with *merge* masking, so yes, false dep.  Although since you mention it, the value doesn't matter, just dep-breaking, so I should fix the comment.  I had a brain-fart when writing this answer and was thinking the value mattered for correctness, like it was ORing into it or something.  But of course it isn't.  GCC also uses xor-zeroing, but that's because it loves dep-breaking.